# How to resolve external JavaScript assets URL issue

Tags: javascript, url

I have a JavaScript file on `http://localhost:3000`. This file includes some assets (image, fonts), which are under the same URL.

But, the problem is, when I add this script to `http://localhost:5000`, all the assets of that file are using `http://localhost:5000` as their base URL. They should come from `http://localhost:3000`.

```
  // http://localhost:3000
  // script.js
  const image = './assets/logo.png';

  // http://localhost:5000
  <script type="text/javascript" crossorigin src="http://localhost:3000/script.js"></script>
  // image const value is, `http://localhost:5000/assets/logo.png`
```

Comment: you have to give the full qualified path for the assets from different server. if we give anything relative it will pick from the current running server

Comment: It's not possible as `localhost:3000` could be a different URL when I configure it on the server. You can ask to use `.env` but that's also impossible.